# SQL query for finding records where a person is late

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms-designer

I have a table named Employee. Within this table I have an employee id and an employee name. I have another table called attendance which has employee id(FK), date, expected time, time in and time status. I would like to find all the records where for example John Brown was late.

This is how the table looks like:

Employee Table

```
| emp_id  | emp_name   |
| 1       | John Brown |
| 2       | Bob Marley |
| 3       | Rob West   |
```

Attendance Table:

```
| emp_id  | Date      | expected_time |time_in|time_status|
| 1       | 12-Sep-18 | 8:30          |8:50   |Late       |
| 2       | 12-Sep-18 | 8:30          |8:23   |On-Time    |
| 3       | 12-Sep-18 | 8:30          |8:15   |On-Time    |
```

The result should look something like this:

```
| emp_id  | emp_name   | Date       | time_in |
| 1       | John Brown | 12-Sep-18  | 8:50    |
| 1       | John Brown | 17-Sep-18  | 9:00    |
| 1       | John Brown | 27-Sep-18  | 8:47    |
```

How would you express this in a SQL query. Also how do I check the the time to determine lateness, say if pass 8:00 you are considered late?

Comment: What have you tried? How is the behavior different than what you expect?

Comment: I've tried this which works but can I insert multiple records for one person with the same id? Select emp.emp_id,emp_name,work_date,expected_time,time_in,time_status
from Employee emp inner join Attendance att on Att.emp_id=emp.emp_id where emp.emp_id=1;

Answer (score 2):

plain sql:

```
select 
    e.emp_id, e.emp_name, a.Date, a.time_in
from
  employee e
  join attendance a on e.emp_id = a.emp_id
where 
  a.time_status = 'Late'
```

assuming Late is a fixed string, not something you enter randomly

Comment: Right now it is enter randomly but say I want to assign 'Late' or 'On-Time' depending on the time in and expected time, how would I do this?

Comment: when inserting, you'd check the times against each other. in mysql, there's an if function, and you'd write >>>> insert into attendance(emp_id, Date, expected_time, time_in, time_status) value (1[or whatever id is appropriate], current_date(), '8:00', now(), if(now() > '8:00', 'Late', 'on time'))

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, Date, time_in
FROM Employee as e inner join Attendance as a
ON e.emp_id = a.emp_id
WHERE a.expected_time < a.time_in
AND emp_name = 'John Brown'
```

Comment: I believe that should be `Where a.expected_time < a.time_in`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to assign 'Late' or 'On-Time' depending on the time in and expected time then query will be

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_id, 
    e.emp_name, 
    a.Date, 
    a.time_in,
    (case when a.time_in > a.expected_time then 'Late' else 'On-time') as Time_status
FROM 
    Employee as e, 
    Attendance as a
where 
    e.emp_id = a.emp_id
```

Comment: can I use this to insert records?

Comment: yes but table should have same number of fields in which you want to insert

eg
Insert into test
SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, a.Date, a.time_in,
 (case when a.time_in > a.expected_time then 'Late' else 'On-time') as Time_status 
FROM Employee as e, Attendance as a where e.emp_id = a.emp_id

and test table should have 5 fields

or 

SELECT e.emp_id, e.emp_name, a.Date, a.time_in,
 (case when a.time_in > a.expected_time then 'Late' else 'On-time') as Time_status 
into test
FROM Employee as e, Attendance as a where e.emp_id = a.emp_id

Comment: You should read this blog: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Thanks. One question though how do I insert more than records for example John Brown has one record already saying hes late on June 14. Hes now late tmrw June 15, how do I add a record for that person since as it will conflict with the primary key or do I have to add with a new id?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are looking for a computed column. Note, I assume the `time_in` would simply be `GETDATE()` on your actual insert. But here, we use static values for testing. In the DDL below, `time_status` is a computed column based on the `expected time` and `time_in`. If the `time_in` is greater than the `expected_time` then we flag them as **Late**, other wise they are **On-Time**. You could use this logic if you wanted to give them a threshold of 5 minutes, or whatever.

**[CLICK HERE FOR ONLINE DEMO](http://rextester.com/JZSGW99104)**

```
create table #EmployeeTable (
                                emp_id int identity (1,1), 
                                emp_name varchar(64)
                             )
go


create table #AttendanceTable (
                                    emp_id int,
                                    [Date] date,
                                    expected_time time,
                                    time_in time,
                                    time_status as cast(case when time_in > expected_time then 'Late' else 'On-Time' end as varchar(64))
                                )
go

insert into #EmployeeTable
values
('John Brown'),
('Bob Marley'),
('Rob West')


insert into #AttendanceTable
values
(1,'20180912','08:30','08:50'),
(2,'20180913','08:30','08:23'),
(3,'20180914','08:30','08:15')


select
    e.emp_name
    ,a.*
from 
    #EmployeeTable e
    inner join
    #AttendanceTable a on a.emp_id = e.emp_id

drop table #AttendanceTable
drop table #EmployeeTable
```

Comment: Thanks. One question though how do I insert more than records for example John Brown has one record already saying hes late on June 14. Hes now late tmrw June 15, how do I add a record for that person since as it will conflict with the primary key or do I have to add with a new id?

Comment: emp_id shouldn't be a primary key for AttendanceTable, only a foreign key. Thus, it can have as many entries as you like. Only primary keys have to be unique. How you decide to insert multiple records depends on your application though. But the schema is fine.

Comment: After doing this the emp_id for attendance table are now saying null

Comment: @cthegooner i don't understand your comment. if emp_id was a foreign key or primary key, it couldn't be null